# Remplazo sed con variables

Tags: linux, sed

Necesitaría reemplazar una variable en un archivo y por más que lo he intentado con `sed` no alcanzo el objetivo.

Planteo el escenario.

Tengo un archivo config.xml como el siguiente:

```
   <widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
     <enter>PASSWORD</enter>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Necesitaria ejecutar un shell script que cogiera el valor desde el mismo comando y reemplazarlo, ejemplo.

```
$./script.sh config.xml NUEVOPASSWORD
```

Y así obtener:

```
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1">
<name>HelloWorld</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
</description>
<author email="dev@callback.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
 <enter>NUEVOPASSWORD</enter>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Es decir que modifique el valor en la etiqueta `<enter>` con el parámetro dado.

El valor  es variable por lo que no lo conoceré cuando vaya a ejecutar el script.

Answer (score 1):

Para modificar ficheros XML es mejor utilizar una herramienta ad-hoc, pues parsearlos puede dar [problemas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1983854).

Una herramienta útil es [`xmlstarlet`](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/), con la que puedes decir cosas como:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "//enter" -v 'NUEVAPASSWORD' archivo
```

Aquí, mantiene el archivo tal y como está modificando el contenido del tag `<enter>`:

```
<enter>NUEVAPASSWORD</enter>
```

Por defecto `xmlstarlet` muestra por pantalla el resultado de las modificaciones. Si lo que quieres es modificar el fichero original, añádele la opción `-L`:

```
xmlstarlet ed -L -u "//enter" -v 'NUEVAPASSWORD' fichero
```

Comment: Excelente opción cuando xmlstarlet está disponible. Yo lo modificaría para que el tag a modificar sea configurable comó indico el autor de la pregunta en una aclaración. En cualquier caso +1.

Answer (score 1):

El siguiente script the bash modifica el password :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#Modifica un texto de la forma <$1>texto</$1>
#Dejándolo con la forma <$1>$2</$1>
#El tercer parámetro es el archivo a modificar.
#Por ejemplo, si se invoca este script con esta línea de comandos :
#modifica.sh enter NEWPASSWORD config.xml
#contra un archivo que contiene la línea : <enter>PASSWORD</enter>
#esta línea será cambiada a :    <enter>NEWPASSWORD</enter>
sed -i.BAK 's@\(<'"$1"'>\).\+\(</'"$1"'>\)@\1'"$2"'\2@' "$3"
```

¿Cómo funciona este comando sed?
Las `''` son para evitar que bash interprete el contenido y se pase tal cual el texto a sed.
Las `""` son para los parámetros `$1` y `$2` con que se debe invocar al script. `$1` es el tag (enter en el ejemplo) y `$2` es el nuevo password. Uso `""` porque sí quiero que bash los interprete y para evitar que un espacio en blanco parta la cadena.

`s` : Comando de buscar y reemplazar.
`@` : Separador de los parámetros del comando `s`, lo habitual es usar `/`, pero el texto a procesar contiene `/` con lo que no funcionaría, y sed permite usar cualquier carácter como separador del comando `s`. Nótese que si el nuevo password contiene `@` esto no va a funcionar. Se debe usar un carácter que no aparezca. Lo que sigue a esto es la expresión regular del texto a buscar.
`\(` : Inicio de grupo de captura. Todo lo que vaya desde aquí hasta ) será almacenado en \1.
`<$1>` : Parsear el tag indicado.
`\)` : Fin de grupo de captura.
`.+` : 1 o más caracteres. Si las contraseñas de tamaño 0 son aceptables usar .*
`\(` : Inicio de grupo de captura \2
`</$1>` : Parsear el cierre del tag indicado.
`\)` : Fin de grupo de captura.
`@` : Separador de parámetros de comando s. Lo que sigue a esto es el texto que substituirá al que coincida con la expresión regular anterior.
`\1` : El grupo de captura 1. Esto escribe la apertura del tag.
`$2` : El nuevo password.
`\2` : El grupo de captura 2. Esto escribe el cierre del tag.
`@` : Fin del comando s.

Comment: Utilizar `sed` para modificar un XML es bastante frágil. Es mejor utilizar un XML parser.

Comment: @fedorqui en general así es. Para este caso en concreto es suficiente. Con la ventaja de que sed está instalado por defecto en muchos sistemas y xmlstarlet no. Pero si xmlstarlet está disponible yo también lo usaría.

Comment: Nótese por cierto que si usas `-r` no necesitarás escapar los bloques de captura: `sed -r 's@(<...>)`, etc. Por otra parte, dado que estás capturando una etiqueta que siempre será `<etiqueta>` y luego `</etiqueta>`, puede ser interesante utilizar la referencia `\1` en el primer bloque: `<(etiqueta>)xxx</\1`. Así te evitas tener que escribirlo otra vez.

Answer (score 0):

Para reemplazar cadenas, usa `sed -i 's/ORIGINAL/NUEVA/' archivo`
En el caso concreto que muestras, seria:

```
sed -i 's/>PASSWORD</>NUEVAPASSWORD</' config.xml
```

Como verás, he incluido los caracteres `>` y `<`, para asegurar la coincidencia; formarian parte de las palabras a buscar/reemplazar, no del comando.

Comment: Olvidé comentar un dato importante, el valor <enter> es variable por lo que no lo conoceré cuando vaya a ejecutar el script por lo tanto este metodo no valdría, gracias por la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Tengo la solución y la pongo por si alguien se encontrase en una situación similar.

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
file=$1
sed -i "s/^\( *<enter>\)\([^>]*\)</\1$2</" "$1"
```

Y la ejecución del comando completo sería tal que así:

```
$./script.sh config.xml NEWPASSWORD
```

En mi caso funciona perfectamente.